# Different binary search outputs even though the list stays about the same

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to understand binary searching. I wrote a code in which inventory is an array of 5 elements and input a particular item and then search the item using the binary search technique. This is my code:

```
inventory=["10", "50", "100", "150", "200"]

SearchItem=input("Enter item: ")

LB=0
UB=len(inventory)-1
Found=False

while Found==False and LB <= UB:
    Mid=(LB + UB)//2
    if inventory[Mid]==SearchItem:
        print("Item found in the position: ", Mid + 1)
        Found=True
    elif SearchItem>inventory[Mid]:
        LB= Mid + 1
    else:
        UB= Mid - 1

if Found==False:
    print("Item doesn't exist.")
```

What's the need for `-1` in `len(inventory)-1`? I was trying to find out what the -1 meant here but am coming across more complicated codes.

How does `SearchItem` know if `SearchItem` is > or < `inventory[Mid]`? Cause if it does, shouldn't it be automatically known by `inventory[Mid]` where `SearchItem` is at? I also tried adding both integers and strings to the inventory as:

```
inventory=["a", "10", "50", "100", "200"]
```

and:

```
inventory=["10", "50", "100", "200", "a"]
```

but it comes with the following outputs respectively:

```
Enter item: a
Item found in the position:  5
```

.

```
Enter item: a
Item doesn't exist.
```

Why do these two inventories have different outputs? Cause if `inventory[Mid]` knows where `SearchItem` lies, shouldn't the position of `a` be found?

Comment: To enable a binary search, the target must be sorted. Your `inventory` list is not sorted. You should just sort it first and then perform the binary search.

Comment: How does a list that contains both string and numeric values sort out?

Comment: The short answer is `lexicographically`. (All the versions of `inventory` that you show only contain strings).

Comment: It's because whenever I make a list (named inventory here) with any variable other than string, it doesn't ouput correctly - hence I stuck to string. I should have been cleared, my bad. What I meant by that question was if a list that contains both string and numeric values in a string (e.g. "1", "10") - how will that sort out? Do alphabets in string need to be written before the numbers or the other way around? Hope that makes more sense - sorry for the dumb questions :P

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the answer to the question -1 of the length (it makes no sense)
And the error that caused the code to not work was that you stored numbers in the array as strings
Because of this, python compared values not as numbers, but as words (in lexicographic order)
If you remove the quotes in the array declaration and add int() in the input line, then the code starts working as it should

Corrected code:

```py
inventory = [10, 50, 100, 150, 200]

SearchItem = int(input("Enter item: "))

LB = 0
UB = len(inventory)
Found = False

while Found == False and LB <= UB:
    Mid = (LB + UB) //  2
    if inventory[Mid] == SearchItem:
        print("Item found in the position: ", Mid + 1)
        Found = True
    elif SearchItem > inventory[Mid]:
        LB = Mid + 1
    else:
        UB = Mid - 1

if Found ==  False:
    print("Item doesn't exist.")
```